# How to scan a project for "@todo" source code comments

Tags: php, html, todo

Is there any way to scan a codebase for any TODO's and generate a list that can be displayed on a standard web page.

E.g.

> @todo Deprecated function remove......... (functions.php [Line 12])

This needs to work on a local WAMP server.

Comment: Trac has a module for this. What platform / tool / IDE do you want this for?

Comment: Netbeans does this automatically when you load a project into the IDE.

Comment: Eclipse based IDEs do that automatically as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a **Windows platform** or if you wanted to use **PHP itself**, you could use...

```
function getTodos($path) {
   $todos = array();
   $items = glob(rtrim($path, '/') . '/*');

   foreach($items as $item) {

       if (is_file($item) AND pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php') {
           $fileContents = file_get_contents($item);

           $tokens = token_get_all($fileContents);

           foreach($tokens as $type = $token) {
               if (($type == 'T_COMMENT' OR $type == 'T_ML_COMMENT')
                   AND preg_match_all('/^\s*(?P<todo>@todo.*?)\z/m', $token, $matches) {
                  $todos = array_merge($todos, $matches['todo']);
               }
           }

       } else if (is_dir($item)) {
           $todos = array_merge$($todos, getTodos($item));
           continue;
       }       

   }

   return $lines;
}
```

I have not tested it, but it should work in theory. :)

On ***nix**, you could use grep...

```
$ grep -r \b@todo\b ./
```

It's not perfect (it will find it within strings) but it should be good enough. :)

Comment: @alex: alex today you are too active! :D

Comment: @yes123 I've been inactive the last few days :)

Comment: Is there Windows/WAMP alternative to grep?

Comment: @James Thanks, feel free to let me know if any bugs :) It also assumes your `@todo` is in a comment and the todo portion spans that line only. If not, modify the regex to suit.

Answer (score 4):

Phpdoc can generate html files from the comments and methods in your codebase. It will also show todos etc.

http://www.phpdoc.org/

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm has an ability to pull up all the todo files, I use it before making commits very nice function and works out of the box.

Its Free for open source Licences, 
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

there are various other licences available 
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/buy/index.jsp

[I am not affiliated with Jetbrains just a developer that likes to use it]